# Using scipy pdist on pandas data frames (and) lists

Tags: python, list, numpy, pandas, scipy

I've run into an odd problem yet again.

Suppose I have the following dummy data frame (by way of demonstrating my problem):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import string

# Test data frame
N = 3
col_ids = string.letters[:N]
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randn(5, 3*N), 
    columns=['{}_{}'.format(letter, coord) for letter in col_ids for coord in list('xyz')])

df
```

This produces:

```
     A_x         A_y         A_z         B_x         B_y         B_z         C_x         C_y         C_z
0   -1.339040    0.185817    0.083120    0.498545   -0.569518    0.580264    0.453234    1.336992   -0.346724
1   -0.938575    0.367866    1.084475    1.497117    0.349927   -0.726140   -0.870142   -0.371153   -0.881763
2   -0.346819   -1.689058   -0.475032   -0.625383   -0.890025    0.929955    0.683413    0.819212    0.102625
3    0.359540   -0.125700   -0.900680   -0.403000    2.655242   -0.607996    1.117012   -0.905600    0.671239
4    1.624630   -1.036742    0.538341   -0.682000    0.542178   -0.001380   -1.126426    0.756532   -0.701805
```

Now I would like to use `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist` on this pandas data frame. This turns out to be a rather non-trivial process. What `pdist` does is to compute the distance between m points using Euclidean distance (2-norm) as the distance metric between the points. The points are arranged as m n-dimensional row vectors in the matrix X ([source](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html)).

So, there are a couple of things that one has to do to create a function that operates on a pandas data frame, such that the pdist function can be used. You will note that pdist is convenient when the number of points gets very large. I've tried making my own, which works for a one-row data-frame, but I cannot get it to work, ideally, on the whole data frame at once.

Here's my attempt:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import string

def Euclidean_distance(df):
    EcDist = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index) # results container
    arr = df.values # Store data frame values into a numpy array
    tag_list =  [num for elem in arr for num in elem] # flatten numpy array into single list
    tag_list_3D = zip(*[iter(tag_list)]*3) # separate list into length = 3 sub-lists, that pdist() can work with
    EcDist = pdist(tag_list_3D) # the distance between m points using Euclidean distance (2-norm)
    return EcDist
```

First I begin my creating a results container in pandas form, to store the result in. Secondly I save the pandas data frame as a numpy array, in order to get it into list form in the next step. It has to be list form because the `pdist` function does only operate on lists. When saving the data frame into an array, it stores it as a list within a list. This has to be flattened which is saved in the 'tag_list' variable. Thirdly, the tag_list is furthered reduced into sub-lists of length three, such that the x, y and z coordinates can be obtained for each point, which can the be used to find the Euclidean distance between all of these points (in this example there are three points: A,B and C each being three dimensional).

As said, the function works if the data frame is a single row, but when using the function in the given example it calculates the Euclidean distance for 5x3 points, which yields a total of 105 distances. What I want it to do is to calculate the distances per row (so pdist should only work on a 1x3 vector at a time). Such that my final results, for this example, would look something like this:

```
   dist_1    dist_2    dist_3
0  0.807271  0.142495  1.759969
1  0.180112  0.641855  0.257957
2  0.196950  1.334812  0.638719
3  0.145780  0.384268  0.577387
4  0.044030  0.735428  0.549897
```

(these are just dummy numbers to show the desired shape)

Hence how do I get my function to apply to the data frame in a row-wise fashion? 
Or better yet, how can I get it to perform the function on the entire data frame at once, and then store the result in a new data frame?

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you want?  Are you saying that, for each row of your DataFrame, you want a new row that contains the pairwise distances between the three points in that row?  You seem to indicate that you want to extend this for more points, but if you add more points per row your DataFrame will become quite unwieldy.  Why not have separate rows for each point, with an extra column that specifies a "group ID"?

Comment: You can't get what you want from `scipy.spatial.distance`. I know, because I am working on an enhancement to it that would allow to do what you are after, see the PR [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/3163). Maybe in 0.14...

Comment: @BrenBarn, Ok, suppose I have a matrix array. The rows of the array contain 3d coordinates for points in space like this [(x,y,z),...,(x,y,z)]. Now I want a function which calculates the Euclidean distances between all those points on that row. Further suppose I want to do the same thing on all the rows of the matrix. In my case I have 12 points per row, so there will be 66 (n(n-1)/12) edges, if we view the points as a Complete graph. Hence, my question is thus: how would one do a function like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have "groups" of points.  In your example each group has three points, which you call A, B and C.  A is represented by three columns A_x, A_y, A_z, and likewise for B and C.

What I suggest is that you restructure your "wide-form" data into a "long" form in which each row contains only *one* point.  Each row then will have only *three* columns for the coordinates, and then you will add an additional column to represent which group a point is in.  Here's an example:

```
>>> d = pandas.DataFrame(np.random.randn(12, 3), columns=["X", "Y", "Z"])
>>> d["Group"] = np.repeat([1, 2, 3, 4], 3)
>>> d
           X         Y         Z  Group
0  -0.280505  0.888417 -0.936790      1
1   0.823741 -0.428267  1.483763      1
2  -0.465326  0.005103 -1.107431      1
3  -1.009077 -1.618600 -0.443975      2
4   0.535634  0.562617  1.165269      2
5   1.544621 -0.858873 -0.349492      2
6   0.839795  0.720828 -0.973234      3
7  -2.273654  0.125304  0.469443      3
8  -0.179703  0.962098 -0.179542      3
9  -0.390777 -0.715896 -0.897837      4
10 -0.030338  0.746647  0.250173      4
11 -1.886581  0.643817 -2.658379      4
```

The three points with Group==1 correspond to A, B and C in your first row; the three points with Group==2 correspond to A, B, and C in your second row; etc.

With this structure, computing the pairwise distances by group using `pdist` becomes straightforward:

```
>>> d.groupby('Group')[["X", "Y", "Z"]].apply(lambda g: pandas.Series(distance.pdist(g), index=["D1", "D2", "D3"]))
             D1        D2        D3
Group                              
1      2.968517  0.918435  2.926395
2      3.119856  2.665986  2.309370
3      3.482747  1.314357  2.346495
4      1.893904  2.680627  3.451939
```

It is possible to do a similar thing with your existing setup, but it will be more awkward.  The problem with the way you set it up is that you have encoded critical information in a difficult-to-extract way.  The information about which columns are X coordinates and which are Y or Z coordinates, as well as the information about which columns refer to point A versus B or C, in your setup, is encoded in the *textual names* of the columns.  You as a human can see which columns are X values just by looking at them, but specifying that programmatically requires parsing the string names of the columns.

You can see this in how you made the column names with your `'{}_{}'.format(letter, coord)` business.  This means that in order to get to use `pdist` on your data, you will have to do the reverse operation of parsing the column names as strings in order to decide which columns to compare.  Needless to say, this will be awkward.  On the other hand, if you put the data into "long" form, there is no such difficulty: the X coordinates of all points line up in *one* column, and likewise for Y and Z, and the information about which points are to be compared is also contained in *one* column (the "Group" column).

When you want to do large-scale operations on subsets of data, it's usually better to split out things into separate rows.  This allows you to leverage the power of `groupby`, and is also usually what is expected by scipy tools.